# What exactly is missing from MetadataReference.CreateFromFile while loading an assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard, .net-4.8

I have an .NET 6.0 Web app, referencing a class library that targets both `netstandard2.0` and
`net48`.
I am trying to load the `Dapper.Contrib` assembly in my class library project.

```
// Here it goes to C:\MY_NET6.0_APP_PATH\bin\Debug\net6.0
MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Dapper.Contrib.Extensions.TableAttribute).Assembly.Location));
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile("C:\\CLASS_LIB_PATH\\bin\\Debug\\net48\\Dapper.Contrib.dll"));
```

When it goes to net6.0 path it doesn't work, but when it goes to class library debug path(2nd line) it works.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you have netstandard2.0 installed on machine?  Check installed software on machine.  From START type Control Panel Programs : Program and Features.  check under Microsoft.

Comment: Nope, that's not the issue.

Comment: What version of Net is the library that doesn't work?